# Integrate Ubuntu 18.04 box with one AD domain and user with other AD domain

Tags: authentication, active-directory, kerberos

I will try to explain my problem as simple as I can. I have the following problem:

Our organization has two Active Directory forests, in one hand **computer.forest.com** has the computer objects, in the other hand **user.forest.com** has the user objects, for example:

**laptopOne@computer.forest.com** is used by **guyOne@user.forest.com**

So, I need to know if it is posible to achieve joining the ***Ubuntu boxes to computer.forest.com*** and at the same time, get ***user authentication with user.forest.com***?

I used krb5-user from command line to get kerberos ticket, and it works. But the real solution for us is integrate boxes and user into different domains and get full authentication for both elements.

I appreciate your time!